# Multiple usb webcams with their own calibration file

Tags: ros, usb-camera, camera, usb-cam, usb-cam-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launched two webcams with the usb_cam package (ROS Indigo).

My launchfile is very simple:

```
<launch>
  <node name="left" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="960" />
    <param name="image_height" value="720" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="my_stereo/left" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
      </node>

  <node name="right" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="960" />
    <param name="image_height" value="720" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="my_stereo/right" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

And the correct output is

```
[ INFO] [1508058286.935975255]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1508058286.936074756]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/marcor/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1508058286.936820975]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1508058286.936874935]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/marcor/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1508058286.936916388]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video0) at 960x720 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS
[ INFO] [1508058286.937664502]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video1) at 960x720 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS
```

All works and webcams are correctly published.
My question is: both camera are launched with the same calibration file. There is a way to set different calibraton .yaml files for every different camera? (I already have these files, left.yaml and right.yaml)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273049/multiple-usb-webcams-with-their-own-calibration-file/) by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2017-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`usb_cam` reads a `camera_info_url` parameter at startup. From the [parameter documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam#Parameters):

> `~camera_info_url` (string, default: '')
>
> An url to the camera calibration file that will be read by the CameraInfoManager class

You can use that to provide `package://` or `file://` urls to the `left.yaml` and `right.yaml` that you have.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on 2017-10-15**:
Thank you very much